# Combining two count queries from same source

Tags: mysql, database

I have two queries that return a list of service items with a count.  One is for the entire database, and the other is for a specified period.  They work great individually, but I would like to optimize them into a single query.

The two queries are:

```
SELECT service_type, count(service_type) from qba_customers group by service_type order by count(service_type) desc

SELECT service_type, count(service_type) from qba_customers WHERE created_on BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30' group by service_type order by count(service_type) desc
```

I tried a few things unsuccessfully, below is what I thought would work initially:

```
SELECT service_type, COUNT(service_type) AS full_count, (count(service_type) WHERE created_on BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30') AS period_count FROM qba_customers GROUP BY service_type ORDER BY service_type DESC
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All aggregate functions, including `COUNT`, will only include a value if it's not NULL. To count just the rows that fall within a date range, use the `CASE` construct as the count argument. If the CASE returns a value, it's counted. If it doesn't return a value, it's not counted:

```
SELECT
  service_type,
  COUNT(service_type) AS GrandTotal,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN created_on BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30' THEN 1 END) AS FirstHalf2013
FROM qba_customers
GROUP BY service_type
ORDER BY GrandTotal
```

For the `FirstHalf2013` column, if `created_on` is within the target range the CASE returns a non-null value (I used `1` here, but it could be any non-null value). If `created_on` is not within the target range the `CASE` returns `NULL` which means the row is not counted.

Comment: I was trying to use a case, but didn't have the 'THEN 1 END'.  I read a couple other answers and figured it out moments after you posted.  Thank you very much for your answer!  I am terrible at combining/optimizing queries, and I have more to do tonight, so keep an eye out! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try it using the case statement:

```
SELECT service_type, 
       count(service_type) as full_count,
       sum(case when created_on between '2013-01-01' and '2013-06-30' then 1 else 0 end) as period_count 
  FROM qba_customers 
 GROUP by service_type
 ORDER by service_type desc
```